# how can i get the date of the likes that have been set by users in my fan page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I own a fan page and users clicking likes on stuff  how can I get the date of the likes?
today to get all the page info I just:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1594970441xxx427/feed?access_token=2227470......
```

as 1594970441xxx427 is the fan page im administrating

Comment: what do you mean ? im doing it in c++ but the examples can be in any form